# AIR for iOS -Quick Publish vs Ad Hoc -optimization difference?

Tags: ios, air

I normally simply use the  'Quick publish' option for single kiosk based AIR for iOS apps.

Is there additional optimization that occurs during compilation if using the 'Ad Hoc' option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are four different build options (at least in Flash Builder):

1. Ad Hoc Release Build
2. Distribution Release Build
3. Standard Debug Build
4. Fast Debug Build

Release builds, standard debug, and fast debug are all substantially different in terms of performance.

- The release builds are meant to be final releases and take 5-30 minutes to build, depending on CPU and RAM. Ad Hoc allows you to install only on specific devices specified in your mobileprovision file. Distribution creates a build you can actually submit to the iOS App Store
- Standard debug allows for debug mode in a close-to-release-mode environment and takes roughly the same time as release builds, though are generally a bit quicker to build. It is not as fast as release, but you won't notice much difference in normal activities. In some activities, you will however. On my last app, I had to decode WAV files to be playable on device. In standard mode, that was a 10-15 second task on an iPhone 4S. Using ad-hoc, it was less than a second. However, most parts of the app should perform relatively close to what a release build would. The only time you might notice a difference in a simple application is in Flex View instantiation
- Fast Debug is incredibly slow. It will build in seconds, comparable to a standard SWF or an AIR for Android app. You will definitely notice a drop in performance using this and it should only be used for rapid testing where you are building, changing a single value, building again, changing another value, etc.

For anything that is being used outside of development, you **should always** use release builds. They are far more optimized and that is what they are meant for. I'm unsure what Quick Publish is (I assume that is a Flash Pro option?), but my guess is it matchesup to one of the debug modes. Determine how quickly it builds and that should help indicate which one. Either way, for a kiosk app you should definitely be using ad hoc release builds.